# Билд с использованием Build System - Gradle(new) Unity

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-editor

При билде ошибка не могу найти решение, нужно именно в gradle сбилдить пробовал уже отключать в манифесте `android:debuggable="false"` безрезультатно

Ошибка

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
E:/jdk201711\bin\java.exe -classpath "E:\Unity 5.6.1f1\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleRelease"
```

```
в логах такое:
`CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
E:/jdk201711\bin\java.exe -classpath "E:\Unity 5.6.1f1\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:


* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleOut'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by using the command line flag -Dcom.android.build.gradle.overridePathCheck=true, or adding the line com.android.build.gradle.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
]
stdout[

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 3.784 secs
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()`
```

Comment: Editor.log посмотрите. Там более подробные логи будут.

Comment: Ещё уберите `android:debuggable` из манифестов.

Comment: его вовсе убрал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в банальной русскоязычной директорией в пути проекта